# javascript: convert hexadecimal value into signed 8-bit integer

Tags: javascript, parseint

I need a way of getting a signed 8-bit integer from a hexadecimal value using JavaScript. So far I have tried using `parseInt(value, 8)` but it seems to be deprecated and I get `parseInt(0xbd, 8) = 0` (when it's supposed to give `-67`).

How can I do this?

Comment: I gave a solution for a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34679269/2102748, hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was just searching for a solution to this in javascript. The answer from splig does not seem correct, but it lead me to the solution.

I believe you should be subtracting 256 from num when (num > 127).

```js
var num = parseInt('ff', 16);
if (num > 127) { num = num - 256 }
alert(num);
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of parseInt is the radix, you need 16 as it's hex 
because you've told it it's hex the 0x is optional.

As you're wanting to do an 8 bit signed int you'll need convert it to signed manually - try something like

```
var num = parseInt('bd', 16);
if (num > 127) { num = 128 - num }
alert(num);
```