# JavaScript: How to clear most significant bit?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a coding challenge that tasks me with converting an integer to a hex value and clearing the MSB. I can use (####).toString(16) to get the integer into a hex but I'm not sure how to clear the MSB.

Comment: you might have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468474/javascript-convert-a-hex-signed-integer-to-a-javascript-value

Comment: How many bits do your integers have (i.e. which one is the MSB)?

Comment: No, you should *not* get your number into a string. Just use bitwise operators.

Comment: @Bergi they will be 16-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To [unset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/1048572) the MSB in a 16 unsigned integer, just use

```
value &= 0x7FFF;
```

Comment: Yep, this gave me the outcome I needed. Thanks!